# Retrieving parameters in URL with Java

Tags: java, url, servlets, parameters

I have a little Servlet that uses XSL and XML to generate PDF.
Since I want to specify the files via URL I need to get those Parameters from there:

```
localhost/Servlet?xml=c:\xml\test.xml&xsl=c:\xsl\test.xsl
```

so the parameters that I need are

```
 c:\xml\test.xml
 c:\xsl\test.xsl
```

and those need to be read into the variables xml-file and xsl-file.

I have this but that doesn't really help me I guess since I don't know how to apply the values into the variables:

```
Map para = request.getParameterMap();
java.util.Iterator it = params.keySet().iterator();

while ( it.hasNext() )
{
    String key = (String) it.next();
    String value = ((String[]) para.get( key ))[ 0 ];
}
```

Any idea on how to do that?

Thanks,

TheVagabond

Comment: Sending file paths as URL parameters is a **very** bad idea for several reasons: 1.) it gives unneeded information about your system away, 2.) it's often hard to make sure that only "valid" files are referenced, 3.) it makes switching to another system internally harder (since you'll still need to handle file names), 4.) I'm sure there are plenty of other reasons ...

Comment: Ties your servlet deployment to the same filesystem as the source files ?

Comment: I know that it is not a good idea but in this special case it is wanted that way... so I do it :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SERVLET must be request, yes?

> String xml_path= request.getParameter("xml");
>
> String xsl_path=request.getParameter("xsl");

Answer (score 3):

I think you simply want [request.getParameter(String param)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)

e.g.

```
String xml = request.getParameter("xml");
```

Note (for future reference) that the above won't handle *multiple* `xml` parameters. For that you should use [request.getParameterValues(String param)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29)

As noted above you probably shouldn't be passing filenames around. In preference I would upload the file, generate the PDF and make that available (simply via the response, or perhaps store it local to your servlet deployment and return an id for later retrieval?)

Comment: There is only one xml and one xsl Parameter

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with this?

```
String xsl = request.getParameter("xsl");
String xml = request.getParameter("xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just get parameters by name with `HttpServletRequest.getParameter()`...

```
String xml-file = request.getParameter("xml");
String xsl-file = request.getParameter("xsl");
```