# How can I get attribute values from get in server

Tags: javascript, java

How acn I get the attribute valuse for name and num1 and num2 in server side

./cgi/addnums.fake-cgi?person=YourName&num1=4&num2=5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving parameters in URL with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452858/retrieving-parameters-in-url-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

- `getParameter()` returns http request parameters. Those passed from the client to the server. For example http://example.com/servlet?parameter=1. Can only return String
- `getAttribute()` is for server-side usage only - you fill the request with attributes that you can use within the same request. For example - you set an attribute in a servlet, and read it from a JSP. Can be used for any object, not just string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `request.getParameter("num1");` (HttpServletRequest)